# How to allow special characters in comment name?

Tags: comments

I was having this error that a random post said it had zero posts (using `comments_number()`) and when I went to the comment section it also said "No Comments" but it listed a comment.

On a hunch I changed the name from "Name @ Website" to "Name - Website" and it started showing the correct post count.

How do I allow special characters in the name?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change the comment from unapproved to approved in the process? I can't replicate the problem you're having on a vanilla install of WordPress. Try disabling all plugins if problem persists.

Comment: Yeah, quite sure. I'd disable plugins but a few of them clear their settings when disabled, so I'm kinda afraid of that.